# Change default encoding in docker container

Tags: python, docker, encoding, locale

I want to change the default encoding of my docker container, everything I have found so far didn't work.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:slim-bookworm

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=ISO-8859-1
RUN sed -i 's|deb\.debian\.org|ftp.de.debian.org|g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources \
        && sed -i 's|security\.debian\.org|ftp.de.debian.org|g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources \
        && apt update \
        && apt install -y \
                        locales \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN sed -i '/en_US.ISO-8859-1/s/^# //g' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen en_US.ISO-8859-1
ENV LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.ISO-8859-1
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.ISO-8859-1

COPY main.py ./

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

main.py:

```
import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

It always outputs me utf-8